# while loop never stop even set a false sentinel

Tags: python

I write a program to find the large-files whose size >= 100Mb,
However,it ran endless on MacOS

I set

```
sentinel = True
while sentinel:
```

and the breaking condition:

```
sentinel = False
```

The complete codes:

```
import os, time, shelve, logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
logging.info("Start of Program")
start = time.time()
root = '/'
# errors= set()
# dirs = set()
sentinel = True
while sentinel:
    try:
        root = os.path.abspath(root) #ensure its a abspath
        #set the baseline as 100M 
        #consider the shift
        baseline = 100 * 2**20  # 2*20 is 1M
        #setup to collect the large files
        large_files = []

        #root is a better choise as the a concept
        for foldername, subfolders, files in os.walk(root):
            # logging.error("foldername: %s" %foldername)
            # print("subfolders: ", subfolders)
            for f in files:
                # print(f"{foldername}, {f}")
                abspath = os.path.join(foldername, f)
                logging.debug("abspath: %s" %abspath)
                size = os.path.getsize(abspath)
                if size >= baseline:
                    large_files.append((os.path.basename(abspath), size/2**20))
            # turn_end = time.time()
            # print(f"UnitTimer: {turn_end-start}") #no spaces beween .

        #write the large files to shelf
        logging.debug("subfolders: " + str(subfolders))
        shelf = shelve.open('large_files')
        shelf.clear()
        shelf["large_files"] = large_files
        shelf.close()
        end = time.time()
        logging.debug("Timer: %s." %(end-start))
        #break the while loop
        logging.info("End of Program")
        #break the loop after walk()
        sentinel = False

    except (PermissionError,FileNotFoundError) as e:
        # errors.add(e)
        pass
```

The codes ran endless, but I cannot find the problem.

Comment: Sentinel is never set to False if there is an exception that you are catching.

Comment: Why do you even need the while loop? If there is no exception, it is executed exactly once. If there is an exception, it loops forever.

Comment: @DYZ Might be that was intentional as a way of recovering from a frequent but unpredictable error. Not the right design, but possible anyway.

Comment: @HansMusgrave An unpredictable error will raise an exception. The exception will terminate the program (and the loop) - unless it is a PermissionError or FileNotFoundError, of course. While it may be the case, it looks like a bad loop design to me.

Comment: @DYZ Fair point

Comment: ty, I try my best to solve the problem with this design to recovering from the error. Could you please provide a hint to the right design to solve the problem? @DYZ

Comment: @Painter, you don't really need the outer while loop at all. Try factoring it out, and catching exceptions within the for loop.

Comment: should I not employ os.walk(root) but to write a customized walk? @aaa90210

Comment: @painter no, that is fine, literally just remove the out while (unindent everything) and see what happens...it will probably just work even without moving the exception inside the loop. the outer while loop is literally not doing anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentinel is only set to `False` when there isn't an exception. Make sure to set it to `False` in your `except` block as well.

To recover gracefully from an error, you probably don't want to wrap every file access in the same try/except block. Rather, you want to have a small try/except block catching an individual file operation, and if that fails you can apply your error handling code (e.g. retrying or logging and continuing to the next file).

Comment: I intend the code recover from the error and continue to walk the folders